# how to get twitter feeds in shopify

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0, shopify

I am trying to get twitter feeds in to my shopify site. I want to get the feeds and style them as I want and thus cant use a app.

I know how to do it using PHP but can not use that code in shopify and looking for a way I can use OAuth in shopify and get the feeds. I tried the shopify docs but without an example its kinda hard to actually get my head around it.

http://docs.shopify.com/api/tutorials/oauth

Thats the link I am using as a guide. If anyone can direct me to an example which might be similar that would be awesome. (google didnt seem to be that helpful this time either)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I know you said you didn't want to use an app, but can I suggest taking a look at [Twitify](http://apps.shopify.com/twitify)? You can use custom CSS to style your tweets. Also see discussions about Twitify [here](http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apps/t/twitify-get-your-twitter-feed-working-in-your-shopify-theme-again-147296) and [here](http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/radiance-twitter-widget-twitter-api-v1-1-137297).

Twitter changed their display guidelines and policies on embedding of tweets on websites in June 2013. [One of the themes](http://themes.shopify.com/themes/mobilia/styles/milan) I used for a client earlier in the year had custom styling of tweets, and they have now [changed it to use the official Twitter widget](http://support.outofthesandbox.com/customer/portal/articles/1082125-twitter-embed-snippet-for-the-home-page) to meet the new guidelines. In fact, the images on the [Shopify theme store](http://themes.shopify.com/themes/mobilia/styles/napa) show how it used to look before Twitter changed things:

[image]

And after:

[image]

I think using an app like [Twitify](http://apps.shopify.com/twitify) would be the easiest way to deal with these changes to embedding tweets.

Comment: +1 for twitify, huge scope for customisability there

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for the suggestion. I did take a look at that before I posted this question. This is a project for a client and I dont think getting a plug in is a viable option. Anyways I found a work around.

Hosted the file on a server and then accessed it. So that resolved the problem. :)

I used node.js to write the script and get the posts as required.

Cheers.

Comment: It would be great to see the solution you've used. Could you paste the code?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter

Have a look at this, it might help. I do not remember the exact solution I used however it was something along these lines :) Hope it helps.. I think it should be straight forward but do let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the app for that Twitify https://apps.shopify.com/twitify or you can Embed a Twitter feed in your online store

Go to your Twitter settings.
Click Widgets to open the widgets menu.
Create a new widget, following Twitter's instructions.
Copy the embed code.